# SSH Configuration with WebSphere and Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, websphere, spring-integration

I have a Web application (Spring MDP) hosted on WebSphere that listens to a messages and generates some text files  on 3 different servers (Unix boxes) using SFTP. We are using Spring integration (DefaultSftpSessionFactory) to establish the SFTP connectivity and write the files to the different servers using user credentials (username/password) for the target hosts.

Now, as per the new requirement, we have to stop using the username/password to connect to the servers and use the SSH key pair instead. We have been given a direction that we have to use the SSH key for 'wasadm' user to establish the connectivity. Here's what I have done so far:

1. Got the public key for 'wasadm' user from WAS Admin team.
2. Got the public key installed to the different server's authorized keys.

Now, my question is that - How do I configure my application so that it picks up the 'wasadm' SSH private key for connecting to the target boxes. (The private key is at the location '/home/wasadmin/.ssh'. Is this directory accessible by the EAR application? If yes, how do I configure the DefaultSftpSessionFactory to use this private key for authentication).

Any pointers and guidance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

-Ashish

Comment: You should be able to load trusted/key store or certificate file in corresponding java object like TrustedStore or X509Certificate or something like that. Essentially nothing prevents you to do new File( some location )..

Nothing expect java.policy file under WAS_INSTALL\java\jre\lib\security can and it will (on default settings) prevent you for accessing files out of default was instalation..

Answer (score 1):

The sftp sample shows how to do that... https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/sftp

You configure it on the session factory...

```
<bean id="sftpSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="${host}"/>
    <property name="privateKey" value="classpath:path-to-key/sftp_rsa"/>
    <property name="privateKeyPassphrase" value="${passphrase}"/>
    <property name="port" value="22"/>
    <property name="user" value="${user}"/>
</bean>

<int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="sftpOutboundAdapter"
            session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
...
```